# Save and reload a dynamically generated Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I trying to create a Windows Form where users can dynamically add user controls at runtime and fill them in.

Is there any way I can save the state of the Windows Form and reload it later?

Sample of Code used to generate the add the user control:

```
private void assignmentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1;
    int index = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));    

    userControl21 = new Test2.UserControl3(assignmentDisplayTemplate, assignmentCommandTemplate,variables);
    userControl21.DataAvailable += new EventHandler(userControl21_DataAvailable);      

    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl21,1,index);

    userControl21.AutoSize = true;
    userControl21.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    userControl21.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 28);
    userControl21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(335, 35);
    userControl21.TabIndex = 0;

    userControl21.Name = "Assignment" + counter;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should look at FluentSharp (https://github.com/o2platform/fluentsharp) where you or your users can do that programatically, for example like this

`var targetFolder = @"C:\O2";
var sourceCodeViewer ="View C# and H2 files in folder".popupWindow()
                                                      .add_SourceCodeViewer();
sourceCodeViewer.insert_Left(200)
                .add_TreeView()
                .add_Nodes(targetFolder.files(true,"*.cs","*.h2"), (file)=>file.fileName())
                .after_Selected<string>((file)=>sourceCodeViewer.open(file));`

See https://github.com/o2platform/O2.Platform.Scripts for tons of examples

for example

- https://github.com/o2platform/O2.Platform.Scripts/blob/master/Utils/Windows/Util%20-%20Notepad%20(with%20REPL).h2
- https://github.com/o2platform/O2.Platform.Scripts/blob/master/Utils/Windows/ascx_Services_Stop.cs

Here is documentation of the web automation api (https://github.com/o2platform/Book_WebAutomation/blob/master/O2Documentation.md) but the WinForms API is very similar (and more powerful: https://github.com/o2platform/FluentSharp/tree/master/FluentSharp.WinForms/ExtensionMethods)

Answer (score 0):

To some extent you can use serialization to store for instance size of a window and then, when initializing the window it can be changed back to serialized values. But in general what you are trying to do is quite complex and challenging task with no quick answer. Below I've added two links. One describes how to create a custom layout engine, other is an implementation of a serializer that saves a state of whole window. That should give you some direction where to search for solution:

- [Saving the state (serializing) a Windows Form](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form)
- [Providing Custom Layout Engines for Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973821.aspx)